# Visual Studio C++ - Link LIBCMT.lib and LIBCMTD.lib (Debug Version)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker, visual-studio-debugging

I want to compile and link my project in Visual Studio 2008 as a Debug Project (MTd). This project includes several external dlls and one of those dlls are just as non-debug-versions available (MD and MT version). Now if I try to link my project it either says redeclaration of stuff in LIBCMT.lib and LIBCMTD.lib or if I try to not allow the non-debug-version (/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT) it has missing symbols.

Now i could use the MT version of all external libs, but i still cant compile & link it as MTd version to debug my project, because of the same errors.

An alternative way (in my opinion) would be to allow redefinition which i thought is possible @ gnu compiler/linker, but i couldn't find anything about this for visual studio's c++.

Any ideas on how to handle this problem? (Remember: it's not possible to compile external dlls as debug-dlls)

As an additional general question: is it even possible to create a debug-project, which uses a non-debug-dll?

Comment: You are trying to intentionally use *multiple* versions of the CRT in your program.  You'd get one for your EXE and another for your DLLs, possibly more.  This is very, very unwise, you'll have major problems passing objects and pointers between them.  Use /MD consistently so there is only one CRT in the program.

Comment: Yeah it's unwise and necessary... because i need a debug-able project and just have release versions of some external DLLs. For the release-build it's consistent anyways.

Comment: You'll need to talk to the programmers who worked on those DLLs.  Surely they can provide you with a debug build.  It is unlikely you will find them here.

Comment: As I mentioned before: it is _NOT_ possible to get a debug build.

Comment: Surely you mean, "I don't *WANT* to get a debug build".  It certainly takes a lot more effort than spending ten minutes on a web site.  Might cost money too, that never competes well with a free Q+A site.  Build with /MD instead of /MDd and cross your fingers that you don't have CRT or allocator problems.  Downgrade your VS version if there's still a CRT version mismatch.  Good luck with it.

Comment: What's your problem? It is still _NOT_ possible to get a debug build. If there would be one, it would be free anyway. No one answered my question - so what's exactly for free? I build with /MD and /MDd - /MD doesn't make any problems (of course) - but i still need a debug version. If you want to be constructive try to answer the question - and stop complaining about asked questions on a site which is made for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that the "correct" solution would be to rebuild all external libs with the same parameters (MTd). As I said, this is not possible. I solved the issue by not ignoring any defaultlibs. Instead i found the paramater i was looking for. In the linker options - additional lines I added: `/FORCE` - which ignores the redefinition of symbols. This is not a perfect solution and it's possible that this won't work for any project - but it's still better than nothing...

In addition I had to set Incremental Link to NO, otherwise the embed.manifest won't build correctly (although I've read this could also be a anti-vir problem).